# CGLIB BeanMap set Field first letter to uppercase

Tags: spring, cglib

In my application, I need to load some Class from jar. I use BeanMap for read/write loaded class. When I read field, BeanMap return `null` value. The instance is valid, but this field has a value and cannot be empty. So I debugged and found that the field name was converted to something unexpected.

In this case, I will load jar in my application. So I use BeanMap for read/write loaded class. This is how I create BeanMap:

```
for (Class clazz : classes) {
    generator.setBeanClass(clazz);
    beanMap.put(clazz.getName(), generator.create());
 }
```

These Classes will use sameone BeanMap.Generetor. But some Class Field name be like this:

```
private Object dXIputXOM;


public Object getDXIputXOM() {
   return this.dXIputXOM;
}

public void setDXIputXOM(Object var1) {
   this.dXIputXOM = var1;
}
```

When I need to access these properties, I do this:

```
public Object getProperty(Object target,String field) {
    BeanMap beanMap = beanMap.get(target.getClass().getName());
    return beanMap.get(target,field);
}
```

At this point, I can't read `dXIputXOM` field. After debug, I saw the `dxInputXOM` resovled as `DXIputXOM`

[debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BcKv.png)

What should I do to have BeanMap resolve the field to `dxInputXOM`?

PS:i use cglib in Spring Core 5.3.25

Comment: the major issue may be happen in the generator,  in general , the private filed is not allowed to  access , so it may  read all get set method and split prefix get set to  get the class filed , so provide more info about it ? or an minimum executable  process ?

Comment: Thx for reply. I also think the problem occurs in the generator, but it should have nothing to do with private attributes, because it is normal to obtain other private attributes. Because I'm not proficient in cglib, I can't provide more detailed operation information. The smallest operation only needs to have a variable with a lowercase letter and a second letter uppercase, and then load it with BeanMap.